# Grouping by multiple columns in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

So my query:

```
SELECT a.term_id, 
       a.update_date, 
       a.campus, 
       a.last_hour, 
       a.enrolled_this_hour,
--      (SELECT SUM(a.enrolled_this_hour)
--      FROM term_enrollment_by_hour h3
--        WHERE a.term_id = h3.term_id
--          AND h3.update_date = a.update_date
--     GROUP BY h3.campus
--      ) as attempt      
  FROM (SELECT h1.term_id,
            update_date,
            this_hour,
            campus,
            last_hour,
            enrolled_this_hour
       FROM term_enrollment_by_hour h1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
            term_enrollment_by_hour h2
         ON h1.term_id = h2.term_id
        AND h1.campus = h2.campus
ORDER BY h1.update_date, h1.update_hour, h1.campus) a;
```

returns a data set similar to this:

`term    update_date    campus   last_hour   enrolled
 14FALL  10/03/14       WEST     06:00       15

 14FALL  10/03/14       NORT     06:00       5
 14FALL  10/03/14       EAST     06:00       30
 14FALL  10/03/14       WEST     07:00       15
 14FALL  10/03/14       NORT     07:00       5
 14FALL  10/03/14       EAST     07:00       30
 14FALL  10/04/14       WEST     08:00       20
 14FALL  10/04/14       NORT     08:00       10
 14FALL  10/04/14       EAST     08:00       50
 14FALL  10/04/14       WEST     08:00       20
 14FALL  10/04/14       NORT     08:00       10
 14FALL  10/04/14       EAST     08:00       50`

If possible, I want to add a column that groups by day and campus, but can't seem to get it to sum correctly.  Here is what I would want the data to look like:

`term    update_date    campus   last_hour   enrolled  group_attempt
 14FALL  10/03/14       WEST     06:00       15        30
 14FALL  10/03/14       NORT     06:00       5         10
 14FALL  10/03/14       EAST     06:00       30        60
 14FALL  10/03/14       WEST     07:00       15        30
 14FALL  10/03/14       NORT     07:00       5         10
 14FALL  10/03/14       EAST     07:00       30        60
 14FALL  10/04/14       WEST     08:00       20        40
 14FALL  10/04/14       NORT     08:00       10        20
 14FALL  10/04/14       EAST     08:00       50        100
 14FALL  10/04/14       WEST     08:00       20        40
 14FALL  10/04/14       NORT     08:00       10        20
 14FALL  10/04/14       EAST     08:00       50        100`

Thanks in advance for the help, and if more information is needed I would be glad to provide.

Comment: It looks like you simply want to count for that campus, so replace `GROUP BY h3.campus` by `AND h3.campus = a.campus`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I made that change and it only gave me data for the EAST campus, and none of it makes sense lol.

Comment: Then there is no match in term_enrollment_by_hour for the term_id + update_date + campus. Maybe a date/time issue? Use TRUNC to play it save: ` trunc(h3.update_date) = trunc(a.update_date)`.

Comment: Could you provide the sample set of data from your term_enrollment_by_hour table, please? Also, I don't understand what you're trying to do with the left outer join in the subquery? And it's missing the table aliases from most of the columns. Anyway, on the basis of what you've said, sounds like a column of `sum(enrolled) over (partition by term, update_date, campus)` might return what you're after.

Comment: @Boneist thanks to your comment, I added this, and it did what I wanted: sum(a.enrolled_this_hour) over (partition by a.term_id, a.update_date, a.campus order by a.last_hour) If you make an answer I will mark it as selected. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still concerned about that left outer join, though; are you sure it does what you're expecting it to?